# Serialization via ObjectInputStream and Transient Fields

Tags: java, serialization, transient, objectinputstream

This question is about ObjectInputStream and how it builds fields declared as transient. Considering a simple use-case of ObjectInputStream

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
SomeClass sc = (SomeClass) ois.readObject();
```

Where SomeClass is

```
class SomeClass {
   int x;
   transient OtherClass y;
}

class OtherClass {
   int z;
}
```

what will be the value of sc.y after ois.readObject ?

I am asking to clarify what i read at [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) which states

"Fields declared as transient or static are ignored by the deserialization process. References to other objects cause those objects to be read from the stream as necessary."

What does it mean that transient fields are ignored? And how can they be read from the stream if they are transient (ie not serialized - how i understand it...)

Matthias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what will be the value of sc.y after ois.readObject ?

`Someclass.y` will be the "default value".  In this case, since it's an object, it will be `null`.

> What does it mean that transient fields are ignored?

They're not serialised - they're skipped.  From the [Java Object Serialisation Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4539):

> A Serializable class must do the following:
>
> - Implement the java.io.Serializable interface
> - Identify the fields that should be serializable
>     (Use the `serialPersistentFields` member to explicitly declare them serializable or **use the `transient` keyword to denote nonserializable fields**.)

... and ...

> The easiest technique is to mark fields that contain sensitive data as `private transient`. **Transient fields are not persistent and will not be saved by any persistence mechanism. Marking the field will prevent the state from appearing in the stream and from being restored during deserialization**. Since writing and reading (of private fields) cannot be superseded outside of the class, the transient fields of the class are safe.

And your next question:

> And how can they be read from the stream if they are transient

They're not in the stream - so, actually, they're not read.  As mentioned above, the end up as the 'default value' for that type (`null` for objects, `0`/`false` for primitives).

> "Fields declared as transient or static are ignored by the deserialization process."

For the most common case, they're ignored by the *serialisation* process - and because of that, they're not in the stream, and won't be deserialised.  However, if you changed the class subsequent to serialising the object so that a field that used to be serialised is now marked as transient, then the deserialisation process will ignore that value when it finds it in the stream.

Comment: Thank you. But do not hesitate to answer my other two questions :-) Maybe you can also justify your answer?

Comment: Thank you for answering again. I hope you see how you answer does not match with the "official" documentation from oracle, where they claim the "those objects are read from the stream as necessary". Also My question is about de-serialisation.

Comment: @Matthias There is no conflict. It is *other* objects (that aren't transient) that are 'read from the stream as necessary'.

Answer (score 1):

> what will be the value of sc.y after ois.readObject?

Its default value: zero, false, or null.

> What does it mean that transient fields are ignored?

It means they are ignored. They don't participate in the serialization or deserialization process.

> And how can they be read from the stream if they are transient (ie not serialized

They aren't. They aren't in the stream to be read.

Comment: "They don't participate in the serialization or deserialization process." does not define the values. Question "Do immediate initializations as ´transient int intVal=7;´ apply on object construction by Object Stream?" remains open.